# Google Forms auto-email script: missing semicolon error when sending HTML emails - solution needed

Tags: javascript

function SubmitHTMLFormNew(e) {

```
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data').activate();
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
      var sent_date  =  new Date();
      var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Email_New');
      var htmltext1 = html.evaluate().getContent();
```

}

in the above code im getting an error for the last line saying missing ; how do i resolve this.

i was trying to create a script that runs on google form submit to autoemail the recipient his score. The code works for plain text email but while trying to send email as HTML, it gives error.

below is the full code

function SubmitHTMLFormNew(e) {

```
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data').activate();
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
      var sent_date  =  new Date();
      var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Email_New');
      var htmltext1 = html.evaluate().getContent();
      var option = {htmlBody: htmltext1};
      var status = ss.getRange(lastrow,22).getValue();

            if(status = " ")
          {
            var secondlastrow = lastrow-1
           

  // code to copy previous row range and paste in last row
          var copyrow = ss.getRange('L'+ secondlastrow +':v' + secondlastrow)
  
          copyrow.copyTo(ss.getRange(lastrow,12))
  
  //code to get email, name score, risk profile strategy and suitable strategies from the last row

    var currentemail = ss.getRange(lastrow,3).getValue()
    var name = ss.getRange(lastrow,2).getValue();
    var riskprofilescore = ss.getRange(lastrow,20).getValue();
    var riskprofilecategory = ss.getRange(lastrow,21).getValue();
    var strategy = ss.getRange(lastrow,22).getValue();
    var subjectline = "Risk Profiling Score"+" "+ name
    //Code to get the contents of the template, subject plain text format

   // var messagebody = templatetext.replace("{Name}",name).replace("{Total}", riskprofilescore).replace("{Risk Profile}",riskprofilecategory).replace("{Strategies}",strategy); needed only when sending in plain text format
    
  Logger.log(messagebody);

  // send function in html format not working
 GmailApp.sendEmail(currentemail,subjectline,option,
 {
    //cc:'dudeshawn75@hotmail.com',
    //name:'Shawn Sequeira'

 }
 )
   }    
   
    //update status after email being sent
    var newstatus = "Email Sent" 
    ss.getRange(lastrow,23).setValue(newstatus)
    ss.getRange(lastrow,24).setValue(sent_date).setNumberFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss A/P")
```

}